# On Darboux Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

My idea was to split the integral into ranges of [0,.5] and [.5,1] as we can then make use of how the function is nice allowing us to easily name the supremum and infimum values in terms of the end and beginning points in the partition, depending on which interval we are in. I was planning on using the partition of a/n for a from 0-n. I am assuming that the upper Darboux Sum approximated the integral over the partition but when I actually try and calculate the Darboux sum over the two intervals I get that the sum over the region [0,.5] is

[image]

but the upper sums over [.5,1] is what I would expect. I was wondering if I was missing something in my thought process here. My texts definition of a Darboux sum is below

[image]

Comment: Your idea is fine. Alternatively, you might split up the $sums$, doing one for $x^2$ and one for $x$ and then combining them.

Comment: But when I split them the sum for [0,.5] isn't; equal to what I have to show and that is where I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ and then to use the consequence embedded in Theorem 4.2.4.

Another one (as suggested in the comments) is to compute two separate integrals,
$\int_0^1 x^2 dx$ and $\int_0^1 x dx$, and look at their upper Darboux sums, leveraging the monotony of the respective functions:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\nu (i/\nu)^21/\nu, $$ 
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^\nu (i/\nu)1/\nu. $$

Your idea also leverages monotony, and it seems to require a lower Darboux sum for $\int_0^{0.5} f(x) dx$, $$\sum_{i=1}^n f(i\cdot 0.5/n)0.5/n, $$ 
and an upper Darboux sum for $\int_{0.5}^1 f(x) dx$, 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(0.5+i\cdot 0.5/n)0.5/n = \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} f(i\cdot 0.5/n)0.5/n$$
(Using $f(x)=x^2-x$ notation above.)

Together, they give:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n} f(i\cdot 0.5/n)0.5/n$$
If we take $\nu = 2n$, we get what we need.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? If I show it is Riemann I get that the upper sum is equal to that summation but how does that help? As wouldn't I still need to find the upper sum?

Comment: The theorem says that the upper Darboux integral can then be computed the same way one would compute a Riemann integral as a limit.